# Is there Any Better Way For This Linq to Sql Group By

Tags: c#, t-sql, linq-to-sql

Is there a better way to write such a linq2sql group by code? It seems too long compared with a T-SQL version and seems It will like to be in trouble with performance.

```
var Result = (
    // [ 1. JOIN
    from l in db.Lists
    where l.ProfileID == ID
    join item in db.Items on l.ID equals item.ListID into ListItem
    //orderby l.CreateDate descending
    // ] 

    // [ 2. JOIN - 1. GROUPBY
    from l_item in ListItem.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join için
    group l_item by new { 
        l.CategoryID, 
        l.CreateDate,
        l.Header,
        Min_ItemListID = ListItem.Min(c=>c.ListID)
    } into G_List
    join i_photo in db.ItemPhotos on G_List.Key.Min_ItemListID equals i_photo.ItemID into ListItem2
    // ] 

    // [ 2. GROUPBY
    from ll_item in ListItem2.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group ll_item by new {
        G_List.Key.CategoryID, 
        G_List.Key.CreateDate,
        G_List.Key.Header, 
        G_List.Key.Min_ItemListID,
        Min_ItemPhoto_FileName = ListItem2.Min(c=>c.FileName)
    } into GG_List
    // ] 

    select new TList.General_ListViewModel
    {
        CategoryID = GG_List.Key.CategoryID,
        CreateDate = GG_List.Key.CreateDate,
        Header = GG_List.Key.Header,
        FirstImageURL = GG_List.Key.Min_ItemPhoto_FileName
    }
);
```

Comment: It would be nice for you to attempt to re-write it yourself, and then ask us help when you get stuck.

Comment: I would advise to simply not use linq for this. Instead, write a stored procedure or view and be done with it...

Comment: I somewhat disagree, I would not push this to an SP unless it is absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the outer join parts, you already have everything grouped using the group join (by having `join ... into`).  I believe you can reduce that query to just this:

```
var query =
    from list in db.Lists
    where list.ProfileID == ID

    join item in db.Items on list.ID equals item.ListID into listItems
    //orderby list.CreateDate descending

    join photo in db.ItemPhotos
        on listItems.Min(c=>c.ListID) equals photo.ItemID into listPhotos

    select new TList.General_ListViewModel
    {
        CategoryID = list.CategoryID,
        CreateDate = list.CreateDate,
        Header = list.Header,
        FirstImageURL = listPhotos.Min(c=>c.FileName),
    };
```